# WebdriverIO: press button, move mouse and then release?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

Anyone knows if it's possible to simulate the following user interaction in an element using WebdriverIO:

- click with left button and keep button pressed
- move mouse with button pressed
- release the button

What I need is to simulate a 'swipe' action with the mouse. I can't use [swipeLeft](http://webdriver.io/api/mobile/swipeLeft.html) (or right), thw following error is outputed:

> Underlying driver does not implement advanced user interactions yet.

I guess that the selenium-standalone server I'm running does not have support for this.

Answer (score 1):

1) click with left button and keep button pressed: [buttonDown](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/buttonDown.html)

2) move mouse with button pressed: [moveTo](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/moveTo.html)

3) release the button: [buttonUp](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/buttonUp.html)

Comment: There is no (more?) such thing as buttonDown at the link you provided :(

Comment: Apparently they updated the links, but you can search for it via the search box. The new link is: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/jsonwp.html#buttondown

Comment: The link that you updated now points to the json wire protocoll, that is I would have to implement the communication with the webdriver backend manually?

Comment: `buttonUp` and `buttonDown` are no longer on the docs page, however I did find they are still present in the typescript type definitions as `browser.buttonDown()` and `browser.buttonUp()`.  I tried it out and it worked!!! 

You can see them used by the library at this link, as well as another way to do drag and drop https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/4c464ad097b7ba99d63f60a477edaf831d4afe8d/packages/webdriverio/src/commands/element/dragAndDrop.js#L24

Comment: Use with caution:
    ```WARNING: the "moveTo" command will be deprecated soon. If you have further questions, reach out in the WebdriverIO Gitter support channel (https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio).
    Note: This command is not part of the W3C WebDriver spec and won't be supported in future versions of the driver. It is recommended to use the actions command to emulate pointer events.````